# Latex showing error in producing Appendix

Tags: titlesec, appendix

The Appendix is being shown as 'Chapter A' but not as 'Appendix'.
Can anyone please help. 
the code I used was:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\vskip 15pt\raggedright}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{5pt}[0pt]
\begin{document}
\appendix
\chapter{Appendix Title}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've added your code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528345/107497.  I also made it into a complete example (although I had to assume the documentclass).

Comment: Thanks for your help. The document class is thesis.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience, but I know that if you want to treat a chapter without giving it the name that Latex automatically assigns you have to put * and then write in the parentheses what you prefer.
But again, I don't have much experience. I would do it this way.

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries}{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\vskip 15pt\raggedright}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{5pt}[0pt]
\begin{document}
\appendix
\chapter*{Appendix Title}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

try to compile it online on [papeeria](https://www.papeeria.com)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It worked. The idea of using a * just didn't come to my mind.

Comment: @Ankit Sharma, I'm glad I was of help. Vote with the upward corner next to the comment if it was useful for you so the topic closes.